# How to get path to file for python executable

Tags: python, path, executable, python-3.5, programdata

I'm trying to get path in python to open and write in text document by already exist path directory C:\ProgramData\myFolder\doc.txt, no need to create it, but make it work  with python executable on user computer. For example if this way I got folder there:

```
   mypath = os.path.join(os.getenv('programdata'), 'myFolder')
```

and then if I want write:

```
  data = open (r'C:\ProgramData\myFolder\doc.txt', 'w')
```

or open it:

```
    with open(r'C:\ProgramData\myFolder\doc.txt') as my_file:
```

Not sure if it is correct:

```
   programPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

   dataPath = os.path.join(programPath, r'C:\ProgramData\myFolder\doc.txt')
```

and to use it for example:

```
   with open(dataPath) as my_file:
```

Comment: i think you want `dataPath = os.path.join(programPath, r'myFolder\doc.txt')`  ? `__file__` will will you path to your script py file

Comment: @Skycc hello, I tried but in this case it does not writes `data = open (dataPath, 'w')` if I use it this way  for example

Comment: not clear on what you want, i guess its because the dir is not there, `dataPath = os.path.join(os.getenv('programdata'), 'myFolder');os.makedirs(dataPath);with open(os.path.join(dataPath, 'doc.txt'), 'w') as my_file:  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by figuring out a standard place to put the file. On Windows, the USERPROFILE environment variable is a good start, while on Linux/Mac machines, you can rely on HOME.

```
from sys import platform
import os
if platform.startswith('linux') or platform == 'darwin': 
    # linux or mac
    user_profile = os.environ['HOME']
elif platform == 'win32': 
    # windows
    user_profile = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
else:
    user_profile = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
filename = os.path.join(user_profile, 'doc.txt')
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    # opening with the 'w' (write) option will create
    # the file if it does not already exists
    f.write('whatever you need to change about this file')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = os.environ['HOMEPATH']
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x, we can

```
import shutil
shutil.which("python")
```

In fact, [shutil.which](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=.which#shutil.which) can find *any* executable, rather than just `python`.